# PowerQuery Join Table by Alphanumeric Min/Max Range

Tags: merge, range, powerquery

I have a parent table and a child table. The parent table only lists ranges of attributes. I'm looking to merge the two to create a proper hierarchy, but I need a way to filter the child table by the parent range first, I believe.

Here is a sample of the parent table:

```
parent_item     start_attribute     end_attribute
A               10                  120
B               130                 130
C               140                 200
```

And the child table:

```
child_item      child_attribute
U               10
V               50
W               60
X               130
Y               140
Z               150
```

The output table I'd be looking for is such:

```
parent_item     child_item
A               U
A               V
A               W
B               X
C               Y
C               Z
```

To further confuse things, the attributes are alphanumeric, which eliminates uses a List.Generate() function I believe. Here is my pseudo code as I'd see it working:

```
Table.AddColumn(
    #"parent_table", 
    "child_item",
    each 
        Table.SelectRows(
            child_table, 
            each ([child_attribute] <= EARLIER(end_attribute) and [child_attribute]>= EARLIER(start_attribute) )
            )
    )
```

*This is a simplification as the child table actually contains five attributes and the parent table contains five respective attribute ranges.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this blog post](https://ssbi-blog.de/technical-topics-english/the-environment-concept-in-m-for-power-query-and-power-bi-desktop-part-4/), which held the key to referencing the current row environment. The main takeaway is this:

> *Each* is a keyword to create simple functions. *Each* is an abbreviation for `(_) =>`, in which the underscore represents (if you are in a table environment, as we are) the *current row*.

Using a new function `C` for `child_table`, we can write

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"parent_table", "child_table", each
      Table.SelectRows(Child, (C) =>
          C[child_attribute] >= [start_attribute] and
          C[child_attribute] <= [end_attribute]))
```

or more explicitly as

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"parent_table", "child_table", (P) =>
      Table.SelectRows(Child, (C) =>
          C[child_attribute] >= P[start_attribute] and
          C[child_attribute] <= P[end_attribute]))
```

Once you add this column, just expand the `child_item` column from your new `child_table` column.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is to do a full cross join and then filter out the rows you don't want.

1. Create a custom column on both tables with a constant value of, say, 1.
2. Merge the `Child` table into the `Parent` table matching on the new column.

[image: Cross Join]

3. Expand out the `Child` table to get a table like this:

[image: Expand Child]

4. Create a custom column with all your desired logic. For example,

   `if [child_attribute] >= [start_attribute] and
      [child_attribute] <= [end_attribute]
   then 1
   else 0`
5. Filter out just the `1` values in this new column.
6. Remove all other columns except for `parent_item` and `child_item`.

Comment: I thought of that, but I was afraid of speed/resource issues because this would produce a table of 10+ million records before being filtered (whereas the end product table should be around 20k records).

Comment: How many rows are in the parent table and how many in the child table? Also, does each child only belong to one parent?

Comment: Parent table has about 2k records and child table has about 10k. No, a child may belong to multiple parents. However, there are no duplicate children, so it is still a one-to-many relationship. *edited*

Comment: If a child belongs to multiple parents, then it cannot be a one-to-many relationship. If a child is not duplicated, then it can only belong to one parent.

Comment: You're right, it is a multiple-to-multiple relationship. Confused myself for a sec.